# transactional replication error due to OS error 3

Tags: sql-server

I am for the first time trying to setup transactional replication. This is from an sql 2000 server sp3a to an sql 2005 server which I believe should work.

I did a quick test on my local machine (sql 2005) using it as both the publisher and subscriber and had no trouble setting it up. I repeated a similar process for the real servers using enterprise manager for the 2000 publisher parts and management studio to setup the PULL subscriber. This all seemed to work and the publisher logs seem to be indicating it was preparing the initial data however I am not getting anything coming over as of yet. I checked the logs and am getting an os error 3. I have included the two log sections I think are important below.

2009-07-21 21:37:42.043 The process could not read file 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\DOMINO_qlsdat_DOMINO qlsdat to PONGOSQL\20090721164816\enbhostname_1.sch' due to OS error 3.

Message
The replication agent encountered an error and is set to restart within the job step retry interval. 
See the previous job step history message or Replication Monitor for more information.

Looks to me like I need to give share permission to the replication data, should I have setup the replication data to go to a share using unc path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS Error 3 is no a permission problem, is a path correctness problem: `Error code: (Win32) 0x3 (3) - The system cannot find the path specified.`. A permission problem would be error 5: `Error code: (Win32) 0x5 (5) - Access is denied.`.

The path D`:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\ReplData\unc\DOMINO_qlsdat_DOMINO qlsdat to PONGOSQL\20090721164816\enbhostname_1.sch` is incorrect on the server that executes it. Usually one has to use UNC paths in replication, I can't know for sure if that is the problem, but it likely is.